# request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module xxxxxx, throttling

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules

I am seeing this log:

```
request_module: kmod_concurrent_max (0) close to 0 (max_modprobes: 50), for module foo, throttling...
```

I don't understand what does it mean?

auto load too many modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that there are too many modules [being loaded in parallel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.8/source/kernel/kmod.c#L152), and that the kernel is waiting for some to complete loading before proceeding with the requested module.

If you don’t see a subsequent error message, either

> request_module: modprobe foo cannot be processed, kmod busy with … threads for more than … seconds now

or

> request_module: sigkill sent for modprobe foo, giving up

then the problem was resolved.